# Why is Browserify not pulling in ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, browserify

I am learning how to use `Browserify` with `Angular`.  When I try to pull in `ngRoute`, I get this error, `Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error`.  Here is my `Browserify` entry file.

```
require('angular');
require('angular-resource');

var DonationController = require('./donor/donation/donation.controller.js');
var DonationService = require('./donor/donation/donation.service.js');

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('DonationController', ['$scope', 'DonationService', DonationController]);
app.factory('DonationService', ['$resource', DonationService]);
```

By adding `ngRoute` as a dependency, I get the above error.  If I pull out `ngRoute` and the `$resource` dependencies, then everything builds.  What else am I missing to get my `Angular` project to be able to use `ngRoute`?  I have for sure installed `angular-route` with `npm`.

Comment: I've never used browserify, but it doesn't look like you have required the angular-route anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you install

```
$ npm install --save angular-router-browserify
```

and then [include `ng-route`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/angular-router-browserify)

```
var angular = require('angular');
require('angular-router-browserify')(angular)
```

Comment: Why do we have to access `ngRoute` in that way?